# Elastic Search composite grouping with range

Tags: python, json, elasticsearch, nosql

Consider the following documents are in my elastic search . I want to group the documents based on rank, but any rank below 1000 must be displayed individually and anything above 1000 must be grouped how do I achieve this using composite aggregation, I am new and I am using composite because I want to use the after key function to allow pagination.

```
Documents 

    {
        rank : 200,
        name:abcd,
        score1 :100,
        score2:200
    },
    {
        rank 300,
        name:abcd,
        score1:100,
        score2:200
    }
Expected Result:
{
   key:{
    rank:101
   },
   doc_count:1,
   _score1: {value:3123}
   _score2 : {value :3323}
}
{
   key:{
    rank:1000-*
   },
   doc_count:1,
   _score1: {value:3123}
   _score2 : {value :3323}
},
   {
   key:{
    rank:300
   },
   doc_count:1,
   _score1: {value:3123}
   _score2 : {value :3323}
}

######## QUery that I tried

{
    "query":{"match_all":{}},
    "aggs":{
        "_scores":{
            "composite"{
                "sources":[
                    {"_rank":{"terms":{"field":"rank"}}}
                ]
            }
        },
        "aggs":{
            "_ranks":{
                "field":"rank:[
                    {"to":1000},
                    {"from":1000}
                ]
            }
            "_score1": {"sum": {"field": "score1"}}
            "_score2": {"sum": {"field": "score2"}}
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I understand, you want to

- Group the aggregations whose value is below 1000 rank to their own buckets
- Group the aggregations whose value is 1000 and above to a single bucket with key `1000-*`
- And for each buckets, calculate the sum of `_score1` of all buckets
- Similarly calculate the sum of `_score2` of all buckets

For this scenario, you can simply make use of [Terms Aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation.html) as I've mentioned in below answer.

I've mentioned sample mapping, sample documents, query and response so that you'll have clarity on what's happening.

### Mapping:

```
PUT my_sample_index
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "rank":{
        "type": "integer"
      },
      "name":{
        "type": "keyword"
      },
      "_score1": {
        "type":"integer"
      },
      "_score2":{
        "type": "integer"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

### Sample Documents:

```
POST my_sample_index/_doc/1
{
  "rank": 100,
  "name": "john",
  "_score1": 100,
  "_score2": 100
}

POST my_sample_index/_doc/2
{
  "rank": 1001,                        <--- Rank  > 1000
  "name": "constantine",
  "_score1": 200,
  "_score2": 200
}

POST my_sample_index/_doc/3
{
  "rank": 200,
  "name": "bruce",
  "_score1": 100,
  "_score2": 100
}

POST my_sample_index/_doc/4
{
  "rank": 2001,                        <--- Rank > 1000
  "name": "arthur",
  "_score1": 200,
  "_score2": 200
}
```

### Aggregation Query:

```
POST my_sample_index/_search
{
  "size":0,
  "aggs": {
    "_score": {
      "terms": {
        "script": {
          "source": """
            if(doc['rank'].value < 1000){
              return doc['rank'];
            }else
              return '1000-*';
          """
        }
      },
      "aggs":{
        "_score1_sum":{
          "sum": {
            "field": "_score1"
          }
        },
        "_score2_sum":{
          "sum":{
            "field": "_score2"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Note that I've used [Scripted Terms Aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation.html#search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation-script) where I've mentioned by logic in the script. Logic I believe is self-explainable once you go through it.

### Response:

```
{
  "took" : 5,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 1,
    "successful" : 1,
    "skipped" : 0,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : {
      "value" : 4,
      "relation" : "eq"
    },
    "max_score" : null,
    "hits" : [ ]
  },
  "aggregations" : {
    "_score" : {
      "doc_count_error_upper_bound" : 0,
      "sum_other_doc_count" : 0,
      "buckets" : [
        {
          "key" : "1000-*",             <---- Note this
          "doc_count" : 2,              <---- Note this
          "_score2_sum" : {
            "value" : 400.0
          },
          "_score1_sum" : {
            "value" : 400.0
          }
        },
        {
          "key" : "100",
          "doc_count" : 1,
          "_score2_sum" : {
            "value" : 100.0
          },
          "_score1_sum" : {
            "value" : 100.0
          }
        },
        {
          "key" : "200",
          "doc_count" : 1,
          "_score2_sum" : {
            "value" : 100.0
          },
          "_score1_sum" : {
            "value" : 100.0
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Note that there are two keys having `rank > 1000`, both of their scores for `_score1` and `_score2` sum to `400`, which is what is expected.

Let me know if this helps!

Comment: If this is the case, parts below 1000 do not need to be aggregated at all

Comment: I think it needs to be. You are assuming that there'd be only one doc with `rank=100` but there could be many. Also user mentioned he wants to sum the `_scores` which is again an aggregation operation. For e.g there are two documents with rank 100 and you'd want to sum their scores. Anyways, I'd let OP come back if he has more queries. My guess is that he may want to further have range queries for docs having rank <= 1000 but let him clarify that.